# Record on laptop from streaming camera via RCA cable

Tags: video, streaming

I have a video camera that only 'streams' the images and has no way of recording them. Currently I'm plugging the RCA into a TV and then recording from that, but I need to be mobile and so need to record onto a laptop.

Will something like this (http://www.amazon.co.uk/tag/av%20to%20usb%20converter/products) work?

Any other ideas?

Comment: That seems like an ideal solution.  Converts analog to digital over USB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EasyCap 2.0 DC60+ is what I use, and they work great. Make sure you get the DC60+ version, you don't want the older versions.

There are a lot of knock-offs floating around--I'd stick with [the official one.](http://www.ezcap.tv/usb-video-capture/ezcap116-capture-card)

There's also a good compilation of capture cards on [this thread](http://forum.telestream.net/forum/messageview.aspx?catid=44&threadid=9881&enterthread=y) on the Wirecast Forum.